# Java Search Array of Strings in MySQL database column with comma separated multiple strings

Tags: java, mysql, search

The following challenge is driving me crazy from couple of days to find the efficient way of performing a reverse search.

I have an event object like below:

**Data_to_search**

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 123456,
        "first_name": "rajesh",
        "last_name": "kumar",
        "birth_year": "2020"
       }
}
```

**Database Table**

| id | SearchTerms(String Type in Database) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ranjan Palekar,2021 |
| 2 | Naresh Thalwar,2020 |
| 3 | Rajesh,2020 |
| 4 | kumar |
| 5 | 2020 |
| 6 | aprajith kumar, 2020 |

The above "Data_to_search" should query in "Database Table" and give the below results only:

| id | SearchTerms |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Rajesh,2020 |
| 4 | kumar |
| 5 | 2020 |
| 6 | aprajith kumar, 2020 |

As you could observe The first 2 from Database are not appearing in end results cause for first one nothing matched and although for the second record 2020 is matched the first string(Naresh Thalwar) didn't matched.

Some ways I could think of but not efficient:

1. I used regular expression to behave like `(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)(?=.*word3)` but the problem with it is records 4,5,6 wont come in end result
2. I know looping DB column by splitting would be most inefficient way

I am using Java latest version(17) and MySQL latest version(8)

Any Ideas/thoughts are really appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Keeping multiple values inside of a single entry is almost always a code smell that your database is not [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), and thus not storing things in a manner that makes operating over the data in SQL simple and "standard". While it doesn't answer the question directly posed, I'd say that fixing your normalization would be the first step to resolving this and future issues.

Comment: As suggested I have given some thoughts to split the search terms to different table but not sure how I can query with an && on the new table with search terms on multiple rows.

Comment: You can keep things like `first_name`, `last_name`, and `birth_year` in a table of `people`. Then this type of search would be a straightforward `OR` clause: `WHERE first_name = :fname OR last_name = :lname OR birth_year = :byear` (using `:param` as a placeholder for PreparedStatement parameters).